# fmincon error during optimization

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to minimize an error signal with fmincon:

```
function test()                                                            
 x0   = [1,1];
 sig = evalin('base','sig');  %importing vector sig from workspace                                             
 xin0 = [x0];                                                              
 [xin,fval] = fmincon(@parameterfun,xin0,[],[],[],[],[1,1],[100,100]);     
 end
 function y = parameterfun(xin)
 sig = evalin('base','sig');
 xin1 = xin(1);
 xin2 = xin(2);
 a = trapz(sig);
 b = sig;
 y = xin1*b + xin2*a;
 end
```

and now I'm getting this error:

```
Error using fmincon (line 708)
User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.
Error in test (line 5)
 xin = fmincon(@parameterfun,xin0,[],[],[],[],[1,1],[100,100]);     %
 execute optimization
```

sig is my current error signal which is a vector: sig <500001x1 double>.

I would appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `size` of the output `y` of `parameterfun` is 50000-by-1 (the same as the size of `sig`). `fmincon` is designed to optimize **scalar** objective function: that is a function which output is of size 1-by-1.

Comment: yep I think you right,thanks.but do you have any suggestion for solving the problem?

Comment: @Navid you need a scalar objective function.

Comment: ,I wish I could,but I do not know can I do that.because I can not change the way of computing y!